# Does one EU country have to accept the gender entry of another EU country?

Tags: european-union, transgender

Situation:

- German citizen B is born in Germany but moves to Estonia at some point and is registered in the Estonian population register with male gender and issued an Estonian ID card.
- B moves back to Germany.
- B changes the gender entry in Germany to "divers" (third gender, passport entry X).
- B is still entered in the Estonian population register (with the incorrect gender "male").
- B still has a part time employer in Estonia (but works and lives in Germany).
- B wants the gender entry to be corrected in Estonia.
- Estonia does not have a third gender and thus (at least according to first responses) will not change the gender entry.

Question: Are there EU regulations or ECJ court cases that clarify that an EU country needs to accept the gender entry of a citizen of another EU country?
("Accepting" means to use that gender in official records such as the population register.)

Barring that, are there regulations or court cases that would at least allow B to choose "female" in this situation?

Note: Since this is a contentious topic, I am **not** asking for opinions on whether third genders are good or bad, or whether Estonia should morally accept or reject this. I am looking for information about the legal situation only.

Comment: I don't know about gender but for topics like marriage the general convention is that they just accept whatever status people have (at least from other EU countries). So back when gay marriage was only legal in some EU countries, these marriages where still recognized as a legal marriage in other EU countries.

Comment: I would think that “transgender” is either a man or a woman, just not what it says on the birth certificate.

Comment: @gnasher729 A transgender person is, in my understanding, a person whose gender identity does not match the gender assigned at birth. The gender identity does not need to be male/female. Nor is the birth certificate relevant because the birth certificate can get updated to match the gender identity, at least in Germany (e.g., by PStG 45b).

Comment: There was a question on [Expatriates.SE](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/26783/travelling-with-nonbinary-passport-to-czech-republic-or-any-nation-with-a-binar)

Comment: It seems unlikely to me that the EUCJ would force EU countries to adopt a gender designation system with more than two genders.  I could imagine them requiring countries with male/female systems to allow people with a different gender designation in another country's system to decide whether they want to be male or female in the 2-gender system.  But doesn't it depend (as names typically do) on the birth certificate along with any legal instruments that make an official change, rather than on the foreign population register?

Comment: @phoog Since the birth certificate is changed retroactively, there would be a German birth certificate giving a nonbinary gender. If Estonia would insist on entering a different gender, that would mean that they make their own determination of the personal data about a foreign citizen/resident. (Imagine for an even stronger example a person who, since birth, never had a binary gender and moves to Estonia. Would Estonia assign them a gender upon entry?) [continues...]

Comment: For example, in the case of marriages, Germany would accept a same-gender marriage performed outside Germany, even though Germany did not have same-gender marriage at the time. That would be similar in spirit – something that normally cannot happen is accepted because it did happen in another country. Now I do not know whether Germany chose to do that by own decision, or because they had to due to EU law.